# Label of contour levels in the Key

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to set contour labels in the key at different confidence levels set in my gnuscript, using the #set clabel command, but it is showing the same label on all the levels. My script is as below:

```
set key inside left bottom Left title 'Confidence Levels' noautotitle width 0.50 height 0.75 box lw 3 lt 7 
set clabel '3{/Symbol s}'
set clabel '2{/Symbol s}' 
set cntrparam levels discrete 2.3,4.61,5.99 
splot [0:360][0:0.9] "test1.dat" with lines lw 3
```

Please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, you might improve your question using this guidelline [ask] and improve the chance of getting a good answer to your question.

Comment: gnuplot 5.2.5 `help clabel` says that `clabel` is obsolete.
Use `set cntrlabel format "format"` instead.
So, maybe `set cntrlabel format "%g{/Symbol s}"` is closer to what you want?